# How can I change SOAP Namespaces in PHP to match a WSDL?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am currently working on a project for the company that I work for. The project will need to make a SOAP request to another company (by means of PHP). I have the SoapClient in my PHP code communicating with the SOAP server of the other company, but all I get is "INVALID XML." After examining their WSDL and the response I notice that their namespaces are different. I need to change my namespaces to match theirs.

For example: The tags in my request show "ns1." and "env.", but theirs show "soap."

How can I change this?

Here is an example of my code, the request that is sent out and the response that is received.

```
---------------- CODE ----------------

  $client = new SoapClient("http://ws.example.com/test/test.asmx?WSDL", array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 'trace' => 1));

  $result = $client->TestFunction(array('Packet'=>'<Email>test@example.com</Email><Password>examplepassword</Password>'));

  $sessionid = $result->TestFunctionResult;

  print $sessionid;


  echo "REQUEST HEADER:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequestHeaders()) . "\n";

  echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";

  echo "RESPONSE HEADER:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastResponseHeaders()) . "\n";

  echo "RESPONSE:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";


------------ REQUEST SENT -------------

POST /test/test.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.4
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://ws.example.com/test/TestFunction"
Content-Length: 352

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.example.com/resumes/">
  <env:Body>
    <ns1:TestFunction>
      <ns1:Packet>
        <Email>test@example.com</Email>
        <Password>examplepassword</Password>
      </ns1:Packet>
    </ns1:TestFunction>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

---------- RESPONSE RECEIVED ----------

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 450
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-PBY: BEARWS2
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2011 15:33:51 GMT
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestFunctionResponse xmlns="http://ws.example.com/test/">
      <TestFunctionResult>
        <Packet>
          <Error>Invalid XML</Error>
        </Packet>
      </TestFunctionResult>
    </TestFunctionResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prefix names are irrelevant. They are not the cause of your problem. It looks like you have a mismatched tag here:

```
<ns1:TestFunciton>
    <ns1:Packet>
        <Email>test@example.com</Email>
        <Password>examplepassword</Password>
    </ns1:Packet>
</ns1:TestFunction>
```

Note the misspelling of `TestFunciton`.

Comment: I changed the tags to remove the other company's private functions. Thats just a typo. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Always paste *exactly* what you're sending in questions. It is a bad idea to re-type. There may be some other reason that they are rejecting your XML, but it should not be because of the prefixes you've chosen for your namespaces, which are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you insert XML tags as values of "Packet". If done correctly (sorry that I cannot check it myself at this time), the SoapClient should escape these as entities, which would destroy your request. Additionally I wonder why your request dump does not show this more correctly, but I assume this might be due to the fact that you were editing stuff instead of copy&paste.

If done correctly, I'd presume, your request should look like this:

```
$client->TestFunction(
    array(
        'Packet'=> array(
            'Email' => 'test@example.com', 
            'Password' => 'examplepassword',
        )
    )
);
```